# Code worked yesterday, wokeup to this error "name 'y' is not defined". Euler integration equation. Python3

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, nameerror

Context:
Integrate using Eulers method with the formulas and plot:

1. dy/dt = ry * (1 - y/ymax)
2. y(t+h) = y(t) + h*(dy/dt)

The code in question:

```
## Establish global requirements
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Create variables
y0 = 1                   # initialize variable
y[0] = y0                # set start point
h = 0.01                 # step size
t = np.arange(1,101,h)   # time range from 0 to 100
r = 0.14                 # given r value
ymax = 50                # give ymax

for i in range(0,len(t)-1):                              # loop from 0 to 100
    y[i+1] = y[i] + h*((r * y[i]) * (1 - (y[i]/ymax)))   # given formula, iterating through all t values to find y values 
    
plt.plot(t,y)                                     # plot time vs integrated values
plt.xlabel('time')                                # x-axis label
plt.ylabel('y')                                   # y-axis label
plt.title('Integrating using Eulers Method')      # title
plt.show()                                        # remove random line of code output
```

and this is the error I keep getting, despite the code working yesterday

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-fe1b96e580a4> in <module>
      5 ## Create variables
      6 y0 = 1                   # initialize variable
----> 7 y[0] = y0                # set start point
      8 h = 0.01                 # step size
      9 t = np.arange(1,101,h)   # time range from 0 to 100

NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Any help would be seriously appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. Solved code is:

```
## Establish global requirements
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Create variables
h = 0.01                 # step size
t = np.arange(1,101,h)   # time range from 0 to 100
y = np.zeros(len(t))     # initialize y array
y0 = 1                   # initialize variable
y[0] = y0                # set start point
r = 0.14                 # given r value
ymax = 50                # give ymax

for i in range(0,len(t)-1):                              # loop from 0 to 100
    y[i+1] = y[i] + h*((r * y[i]) * (1 - (y[i]/ymax)))   # given formula, iterating through all t values to find y values 
    
plt.plot(t,y)                                     # plot time vs integrated values
plt.xlabel('time')                                # x-axis label
plt.ylabel('y')                                   # y-axis label
plt.title('Integrating using Eulers Method')      # title
plt.show()                                        # remove random line of code output
```